# Mystery Web Part

Tags: web-part, web-part-gallery

I'm currently working on the creation of a custom Web Part which simply displays a message on the home page of a SharePoint 2010 publishing site.

When I go to add the deployed Web Part to the page, I can still see an older version with a different name even though I removed the solution - it does not show up in the Web Part Gallery when I append "?contents=1" to the page URL.

[image]

[image]

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Web parts (under Galleries category)

Find and delete the Web Part (you can filter the group column to Custom).